# POST "/admin/users/26/approve_vip" not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to approve the user to be vip,but when I press the button.The page refreshed but nothing changed.The log in terminal is

```
Started POST "/admin/users/26/approve_vip" for ::1 at 2016-12-12 16:33:22 +0800
Processing by Admin::UsersController#approve_vip as HTML
    Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"qYrbaVH/cssY3VBYLw6Hd4wXl42Zz8OqkdHGGoITEeeWtbJ4ZOLOmJF/Jmpx70s9aaL5Yr0vFhqNV9kGHtILpA==", "user_id"=>"26"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 26], ["LIMIT", 1]]
SQL (1.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "is_vip" = 't' WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["id", 26]]
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
(0.0ms)  commit transaction
DEPRECATION WARNING: `redirect_to :back` is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 5.1. Please use `redirect_back(fallback_location: fallback_location)` where `fallback_location` represents the location to use if the request has no HTTP referer information. (called from approve_vip at /Users/a1/JDDstore/app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb:26)
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/users
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)



Started POST "/admin/users/26/approve_vip" for ::1 at 2016-12-12 15:41:47 +0800
Processing by Admin::UsersController#approve_vip as HTML
  Parameters:   {"authenticity_token"=>"uYc9hdEZaYCgfhdmYK3XnyK2lcraPpHWfuXcQ5cRtLyGuFSU5ATV0yncYVQ+TBvVxwP7Jf7eRGZiY8NfC9Cu/w==", "user_id"=>"26"}
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 26], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
(0.0ms)  commit transaction
DEPRECATION WARNING: `redirect_to :back` is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 5.1. Please use `redirect_back(fallback_location: fallback_location)` where `fallback_location` represents the location to use if the request has no HTTP referer information. (called from approve_vip at /Users/a1/JDDstore/app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb:26)
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/users
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

And the code in controller is

```
def approve_vip
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @user.is_vip=true 
    @user.save      
    redirect_to :back
end
```

Can you tell me why it not change the role?
If you want to know more informatian, please let me know. Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: Add the relevant code responsible for updating user record.

Comment: @dp7 Update the question.Please check~thx.

Comment: You paste wrong controller's code. It's same as model's code.

Comment: Use `save!` , that would give you the error message why it is not getting updated.

Comment: @AlexKojin sorry ,I will change that

Comment: @dp7 It's not work,it also refresh but no change

Comment: Check your logs after changing `save` to `save!` in method `approv!`

Comment: @dp7 It's the same. It looks like not get the post.

Comment: Looks like `approv!` method is getting overriden

Comment: @dp7 yes,do you know how to solve that?

Comment: Have you defined any other instance methods as `approv!` or do you have any attribute as `approv!` in user model ?   An unrecommended easy fix would be to write that model code in controller action .

Comment: @dp7 I try that , I write the model code in controller .                                                                                                                            But it still not work ......

Comment: @dp7 I have another method named "approve!".It is similar as "approv!".It can work.Is there can not have similar method?

Comment: @LydiaDai Please update your question , add logs, and controller action after doing changes

Comment: @dp7,the log is the latest time I do this action,I think it is the same as before.And I update the code in controller,Please check.

Comment: @LydiaDai Don't you see any change in log when you change `save` to `save!` ?

Comment: @dp7 Yes, I think so,I put the log when it's "save!"after the old one.Please check.

Comment: @LydiaDai try `@user.update_column(is_vip: true )` instead of `@user.is_vip=true      @user.save`

Comment: @dp7  I tried that and it give me a bug "wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)"

Comment: @LydiaDai I just did a mistake with the syntax of `update_column`, try this `@user.update_column(:is_vip, true )`

Comment: @dp7 It doesn't work but the log changed,I update the question.The first one is this time log.Please check.

Comment: Your log has `UPDATE "users" SET "is_vip" = 't' WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["id", 26]]` , did you verify it in your `rails console` whether user record `is_vip` set to true or not ?

Comment: @dp7  How can I find the user in rails console?I usually use "User.last".But this one is not the last one.

Comment: @LydiaDai  Open `rails console`, then type `User.find_by_id(26)`

Comment: @dp7 Thank you for your patience,it solved.I use this to check is_vip is true.And can you tell me why it can not work when I use"@user.is_vip=true"?

Comment: @LydiaDai check my answer below for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks you have some model callback (may be `before_save`) which is restricting to update the records.

You can use [`update_column`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column) or [`update_columns`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns) to bypass the callbacks/validations and directly make a update query to your db.

```
def approve_vip
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @user.update_columns(is_vip: true) 
  redirect_to :back
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read error's message. Probably the user's validation is failed.

```
def approv!
  update_attributes!(is_vip: true)
end
```

This code give you exception with the error's message.

Comment: I try this ,but it not work.I compare the log with another one ,it don't have "SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "role" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["role", 0], ["updated_at", 2016-12-12 04:47:57 UTC], ["id", 29]] "

Comment: Probably do you have not access to call approve_vip method? Any roles rules? Do you have any before_filter calls before?

Comment: It has this two rules"before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :require_is_admin" but they are for the whole controller .Now I can use other functions as normal.....Only this one can not work.....:(